# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in StringBuilder

Tags: c#, jquery, exception, razor, stringbuilder

I am trying to embed HTML code into `StringBuilder` in Razor View Page but while running i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error.Here is my Code..

```
 @{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach(var row in Model)
    {
     sb.AppendFormat("['{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}','{4}','{5}'],",
     "<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=''>", "", row.CompanyCode, row.CompanyName, row.PrimaryContactName, row.PrimaryContactEmail);
  }
  }
```

and this is my Values from the Console of the developer tool of Chrome..

```
var dataSet = [['<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=''>', '', '73878', 'Systems','hgfjhf','systems.com'],['<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=''>', '', '99878', 'Microsoft Systems','Archit','ems.com'],];
```

Please help me to resolve this.Thanks

Comment: Escape quotes your generated value should be like `[["<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=''>"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate string using escape double quotes `\"` or `""`, so that it doesn't breaks the string when using combination of single and double quotes

```
sb.AppendFormat("[\"{0}\", '{1}', '{2}', '{3}','{4}','{5}'],",
 "<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=''>", "", row.CompanyCode, row.CompanyName, row.PrimaryContactName, row.PrimaryContactEmail);
```